# Get number of active instances for BackgroundScheduler jobs

Tags: python-3.x, flask, apscheduler

I have a simple BackgroundScheduler and a simple task. The BackgroundScheduler is configured to run only a single instance for that task:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler.add_job(run_task, 'interval', seconds=10)
scheduler.start()
```

When a tasks starts, it takes much more than 10 seconds to complete and I get the warning:

```
Execution of job "run_tasks (trigger: interval[0:00:10], next run at: 2020-06-17 18:25:32 BST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
```

This works as expected.

My problem is that I can't find a way to check if an instance of that task is currently running.

In the [docs](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/base.html), there are many ways to get all and individual scheduled tasks, but I can't find a way to check if a task is currently running or not.
I would ideally want something like:

```
def job_in_progress():
    job = scheduler.get_job(id=job_id)
    instances = job.get_instances()

    return instances > 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not great because you have to access a private attribute, but the only thing I could find.

```py
def job_in_progress():
    job = scheduler.get_job(id=job_id)
    instances = scheduler._instances[job_id]

    return instances > 0
```

If someone else has another idea, don't use this.